# Laravel Storage store() is returning HTML?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-storage

I have an application running on Laravel 5.8 that presents several forms to users. One of these forms requires file uploads. I am using a very basic Dropzone.js implementation on the front-end to facilitate these uploads. As soon as a user adds a file to the Dropzone, the application uploads the file by hitting an upload route, which returns the temporary filename. That temporary filename is added to the form as a hidden input, which I then use when processing the form on submission.

All of this works fine, most of the time. On occasion, though, we've been receiving errors that the temporary filename returned by the upload route is "<html", rather than the expected filename string or false boolean. This leads to the form's erroring, since it can't find a file at path <html.

I have no idea why this is happening. I cannot reproduce the error myself, and there seems to be no rhyme or reason to when it happens. No consistent time, no consistent browser or OS, nothing.

Here's the code for the upload route:

```
Route::post('upload', function(Request $request) {
    try {
        $response = $request->file->store('/', 'temp');
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::channel('uploads')->info('File uploaded!', ['response' => $response]);
        return response()->json($response, 200);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        report($e);
        return response()->json('Unknown error. Try again later.', 400);
    }
})
```

Some really odd things to note:

We use Sentry to catch exceptions, and you'll notice there is a log made when a file is successfully uploaded. The last time this error occurred, Sentry caught no exception, which leads me to believe the try block succeeded, but there's also no record of the upload in the logs. Sentry did catch an exception from later on down the processing line, which shows again that the "path" of the uploaded file was <html, which confirms that the try block succeeded here. But why is there no log with the full HTML, so I could perhaps see where it's coming from?

And, ultimately, does anyone have any idea why the store() method would be returning HTML, instead of the expected path on success or false on failure?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$request->file->store()
```

try to use

```
$request->file('the_name_of_your_file')->store($path)
```

This method will do the same, and will return the file path if success or `false` if error. Also, when returning your JSON response, you should return an array:

```
return response()->json([
    'file_path' => $response
], 200);
```

This should do it